# login to a seperate user group in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created a distinct user registration in django.

```
class Trainer(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = TrainerManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='trainer_groups', blank=True)
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name='trainer_user_permissions', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

i have created a user signup from and its working.
I am facing challenges while trying into logging in to the user.
Its always showing "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

any idea on how to specify the trainer user model while logging in?
The new User model is under  TRAINERS app

have tried logging in using the below code

```
def trainer_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('username')  # Use email as the username field
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'Login successful.')
                # Redirect to the desired page after login
                return redirect('dashboard')  # Change 'dashboard' to your desired URL name
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password.')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'trainer_login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Have you added `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py` ?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Add your forms.py logic used to serve forms.